# What is the difference between "int x = (int) x" and "x = (int) x" in java if I assign "double x = 2.3"?

Tags: java, jshell, typecasting-operator

if I assign "double x = 2.3", what is the difference between "int x = (int) x" and "x = (int) x" ? I'm new to java and use python before, in python, if I execute "x = 2.3; x = int(x); print(x)", x is 2.

java:

[image]

python:

[image]

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of textual output, post it as code-formatted text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're re-declaring `x`, so in the line

```
int x = (int)x
```

The `x` on the right is not the same `x` you previously declared. So its value defaults to 0 so `(int)x` is 0. You normally wouldn't be able to have two `x` variables. That's a thing `jshell` lets you do, but in normal Java you couldn't do.

See this:

```
jshell> double x = 2.3
x ==> 2.3

jshell> int y = (int)x
y ==> 2
```